# How to prepend Sidekiq job to beginning of a queue?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

How to prepend Sidekiq job to beginning of a queue?

I know that most obvious thing you might want to say right now is "just add a separate high-prio queue, with a separate worker!", but I'm constrained on resources, so an extra worker is out of the question.

Now, I know that technically [Sidekiq is prepending jobs to the queue in Redis](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/2f147f6619c102ed45c280ca0a809da3b164e38b/lib/sidekiq/client.rb#L264), and [pops them from the end of the list](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/2f147f6619c102ed45c280ca0a809da3b164e38b/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb#L47) to get next one for processing (*which is somewhat counterintuitive, but ok*). Occasionally, to preserve unfinished jobs when terminating, it actually does what I need: it re-queues jobs to the end of the list (== they will be pulled next). So, in the end, does anybody know how to prepend (*well, technically, it's "append"*) a job to the queue so it's performed by the next fetch? Without monkey-patching the Sidekiq source too much, of course. Or, maybe, someone knows a gem that already does that?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm constrained on resources, so an extra worker is out of the question.

You don't need an extra worker, you just have to configure a second queue. Even a single Sidekiq process with a single thread can process multiple queues.

Sidekiq queues are processed in the order given (or by weight, see [Advanced Options – Queues](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues)).

Given this simple config:

```yaml
:queues:
  - critical
  - default
```

An available Sidekiq worker would try to fetch jobs from the `critical` queue first and – if it's empty – from the `default` queue second.

Say you have 3 jobs in the `default` queue and none in `critical`

```
critical: []
 default: [job_1, job_2, job_3]
```

... the next available worker would process `job_1` first, then `job_2`, and finally `job_3`.

If you push another job to `critical`, i.e.:

```
critical: [job_4]
 default: [job_1, job_2, job_3]
```

... the next available worker would process `job_4` first and then `job_1`, `job_2`, and `job_3`.